# Checking if all the values I want are in my table

Tags: python

I want to do a function that takes in a 2D table, which represents a magic square, and check if all numbers between `1` and `size*size` are in the table.

Any ideas for an effective way to write my function?

Comment: Hi Cere, please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your 'tab' variable is a list, something like this should work:

```
for x in range(1, size*size+1):
    if x not in tab:
        print(f"{x} not in list")
        break
```

If you want it to tell you every missing number, remove the `break`. The `break` makes it more efficient if you just want to check whether it is a valid list or not, so it will only tell you the first missing number.

Comment: thanks, it is perfectly working and replying to my question.

Comment: @Cere No problem, would you mind accepting the answer if it worked for you?